# Bivariate Continuous Random Variable - Double Integral Calculation

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

I was working on some textbook exercises for continuous bivariate rv’s and I came across a double integral that I’m not sure how to approach. The premise of this question defines $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ as continuous rv’s and the bivariate pdf as such:

$$f(y_1,y_2) = \begin{cases} 6y_1^2y_2 &:& 0\le y_1 \le y_2, y_1+y_2\le2\\[1ex]0&:&\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

(And 0 elsewhere, I don’t know how to make piecewise functions in latex) [edit: use the cases enviroment.]

A bunch of previous parts of the question asked for verifying the pdf but the question I have trouble with is to find the marginal pdf of $Y_2$. Graphing the region defined by this function yields a sort of filled triangle bounded by the lines $y_1=y_2$, and $y_2=2-y_1$ enclosed by the y-axis.

In my attempt to find the marginal pdf, I tried creating the generalized integral to solve of the form

$$\int_\Bbb R 6y_1^2y_2\,dy_1$$

But I don’t know what bounds to place on my integral. In the $y_1$ direction, the sections for summation are bounded by two different functions simultaneously (both lines mentioned previously) and I’m at a loss. Normally, using the multivar calculus I know I would split the integral in two but as I don’t yet fully grasp the nature of marginal probability in continuous bivariate rv’s I’m unsure on how to proceed logically. Any help would be absolutly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Graphing the region defined by this function yields a sort of filled triangle bounded by the lines y1=y2, and y2=2−y1 enclosed by the y-axis.

So that is: $y_1$ is less than the minimum of those two lines.

$$0\le y_1 \le \min\{y_2, 2-y_2\}\text{ when }0\le y_2\le 2$$

This can be split into two parts, according to where those lines intercept.

$$\large \begin{align}f_{2}(y_2) &= 6y_2 \mathbf 1_{0\le y_2\leq 2} \int_0^{\min\{y_2, 2-y_2\}} y_1^2 \,\mathrm d y_1\\[2ex] &=6y_2\left(\mathbf 1_{0\le y_2\lt 1}\int_0^{y_2} y_1^2\,\mathrm d y_1 + \mathbf 1_{1\leq y_2\leq 2}\int_0^{2-y_2} y_1^2\,\mathrm d y_1 \right)\\[3ex] &= 6y_2\begin{cases}\int_0^{y_2} y_1^2\,\mathrm d y_1&:& 0\le y_2\lt 1\\[1ex]\int_0^{2-y_2} y_1^2\,\mathrm d y_1&:& 1\le y_2\le 2\\[1ex] 0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} \end{align}$$

---

---

PS Indicator variables equal $1$ when the condition holds, or zero elsewhere.  $$\mathbf 1_{y\in A}=\begin{cases}1&:& y\in A\\0&:& y\notin A\end{cases}$$

Comment: I've never seen such notation with the 1 sub an interval. Is this more of a logical operator or is there a simple way to use them in calculation? Thanks!

Comment: It is just a more compact form of a piecewise function. @Alex03  There are variations on the notation, such as characteristic functions: $\raise{0.5ex}\chi_A(y), \Bbb I_A(y)$, et cetera.

Comment: Perfect, this all makes sense. Thank you very much!